# Where can I specify the adapter for MySQL which I need to use along with Play 1.2 framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I know how to configure MySQL database in Play 2.0 by specifying these in application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
db.default.user="root" 
db.default.password=""
```

and putting this in 
    val appDependencies = Seq(
          "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18")

```
in Build.scala file.
```

But how do I achieve the same in Play 1.2 framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to a local MySQL database, put the settings in your `application.conf` file in the following format:

```
db=mysql:user:pwd@database_name
```

(So in your case it would be `db=mysql:root:@test`)

There is no need to add any dependencies - MySQL is already included.

The longer format of configuration would be like this:

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
db.user=root
db.pass=
```

See [Play Framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#dbconf) form more info.

Comment: I had used the exact same configurations! But strangely i had missed      import play.db.jpa.Model;  in my Model class